# i m using Calendar in swing

Tags: swing

I m using Calendar in swing, occurring error, when i click on button , then without selection date it calendar does not dispose. how to implement dispose   functionality when suppose user does not select any date.
    code below:-

```
 JButton btnDate = new JButton("");
            btnDate.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            btnDate.setBorder(null);
            btnDate.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            btnDate.setToolTipText(" Click to Select date");
            btnDate.setIcon(new ImageIcon(SendFile.class.getResource("/images/Calender.png")));
            btnDate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    DatePicker dp = new DatePicker((Observer) textField, getLocale());
                    dp.setSelectedDate(new Date());
                    dp.start(textField);
                }
            });
            btnDate.setBounds(396, 230, 24, 24);
            add(btnDate);

and using class :
class ObservingTextField extends JTextField implements Observer {
        public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
            Calendar calendar = (Calendar) arg;
            DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) o;
            System.out.println("picked=" + dp.formatDate(calendar));
            setText(dp.formatDate(calendar));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `DatePicker` from a 3rd party library? Where is the code for that?

Comment: can i dispose  without selection any date from calendar. it does not hide till user not select any date, how to hide.

Comment: Can't answer without knowing the nature of `DatePicker`

Comment: i had mentioned class "ObservingTextField ", i m using this class for Calendar

Comment: You might try using jcalendarbutton. It's pretty solid.http://www.jbundle.org/jbundle/jcalendarbutton/index.html .